# Emails being replace to Holiday in the United States?

Tags: macbook-pro, email

I recently started noticing that my emails were being replace to "Holidays in the United States" on the default Apple mail app. This is annoying because now I have to send emails from the browser. My name is correct in settings, does anyone know how to fix this?

I am on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a bug with Apple mail for a very long time (Funny because the issue just came back to me today). There isn't a clear solution for this issue, but I just go ahead and refer to this thread when I get this issue:

- [My gmail name comes up as Holidays in the United States](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/qvAg3NmPpSs)

What seems to be the issue is the syncing with Google Calendars. Variations of this bug can be found when your name is changed to one of your contacts.